# Shiny dynamic button press error

Tags: r, shiny

I was expecting this code to write out if the number of times I press the button is even or odd? Instead nothing happens.

my **index.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="shared/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="shared/shiny.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Press me!" class="button">
        <p><div id="text" class="shiny-text-output" style="width: 150px; height: 25px; border: 1px solid black;"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

my **server.R**

```
shinyServer (function (input, output, session)
{
    observe ({
        x = input$button;

        output$text = renderText ({
            if (! is.null (x))
            {
                if (x %% 2 == 0) {
                    "You are even";
                }
                else {
                    "You are odd";
                }
            }
        })
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `class` on your input needs to have an additional `action-button` to define it as a shiny bound class.
Also you need to give your `input` the `id="button"` to correspond to your call in `server.R`.

```
<html>
  <head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="shared/jquery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="shared/shiny.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
  <input id="button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Press me!" class="button action-button">
  <p><div id="text" class="shiny-text-output" style="width: 150px; height: 25px; border: 1px solid black;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Then I don't need the `class="button"`; do I?

Comment: Only if you want any css associated with the button class